# Implement Aliquot Sum and the Perfect Number algorithm

Tags: elixir

Determine if a number is perfect, abundant, or deficient based on Nicomachus' (60 - 120 CE) classification scheme for natural numbers.

The Greek mathematician Nicomachus devised a classification scheme for natural numbers, identifying each as belonging uniquely to the categories of perfect, abundant, or deficient based on their aliquot sum. The aliquot sum is defined as the sum of the factors of a number not including the number itself. For example, the aliquot sum of 15 is (1 + 3 + 5) = 9

```
Perfect: aliquot sum = number
    6 is a perfect number because (1 + 2 + 3) = 6
    28 is a perfect number because (1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14) = 28
Abundant: aliquot sum > number
    12 is an abundant number because (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6) = 16
    24 is an abundant number because (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 12) = 36
Deficient: aliquot sum < number
    8 is a deficient number because (1 + 2 + 4) = 7
    Prime numbers are deficient
```

Comment: I would suggest including some code, even if just partial and make the question more specific. Can you write or find code to generate the factors? That would seem to me to be the only tricky part. If not, do everything else, and then the question becomes, "How to generate factors in elixir?"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. The site is meant to help programmers, but that doesn't mean you can post (what appears to be) homework and expect us to solve it for you. Some tips: Don't post an entire exercise to solve. instead try to solve it, and if you get stuck, ask a question saying what you've tried, and why you're stuck (Do you get an error? Is the program not behaving as expected?)

Comment: it is'nt home work im trying to learn elixir myself  so that this exercice i find it on site of exercise

Comment: You will probably not find anyone that will solve that for you (this site is not for that). I will help you pointing a link of how to generate factors: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_an_integer#Elixir. I hope it helps you to at least start and come back with a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation to get you started, though it'll only work for positive integers and could use some improvements to boost performance:

```ex
defmodule PerfectNumber do
  def check(n) do
    sum = aliquot_sum(n)

    cond do
      sum == n -> :perfect
      sum <  n -> :deficient
      sum >  n -> :abundant
    end
  end

  def aliquot_sum(n) do
    Enum.sum(factors(n))
  end

  def factors(1), do: [1]
  def factors(n) do
    for i <- 1..div(n,2), rem(n,i) == 0, do: i
  end
end
```

Works as expected:

```ex
iex> PerfectNumber.check(6) 
# => :perfect
iex> PerfectNumber.check(12)
# => :abundant
iex> PerfectNumber.check(8)
# => :deficient
```